# difference between tf.matmul and torch.matmul when tolerance >= 1e-5

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

```
gat_key_t = np.random.normal(size = (8, 16, 64, 20)).astype(np.float32)
gat_query_t = np.random.normal(size = (8, 16, 30, 64)).astype(np.float32)

tf_key   = tf.convert_to_tensor(gat_key_t)
tf_query = tf.convert_to_tensor(gat_query_t)
pt_key   = torch.from_numpy(gat_key_t)
pt_query = torch.from_numpy(gat_query_t)

tf_output = tf.matmul(tf_query, tf_key)
pt_output = torch.matmul(pt_query, pt_key)

# False
np.allclose(tf_output.numpy(), pt_output.numpy(), rtol = 1e-5, atol = 1e-5, equal_nan = False)


# True
np.allclose(tf_output.numpy(), pt_output.numpy(), rtol = 1e-4, atol = 1e-4, equal_nan = False)
```

When I multiply two tensors, the outputs of torch and tensorflow are different when tolerance is smaller than 1e-5.

As above, two values are the same until 1e-4, but they become different as tolerance becomes smaller.

How can I make two output be the same in the tolerance of 1e-5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had encountered this issue recently when trying to port a transformer model from `pytorch` to `TF`. Only their CPU version of TF seems to be closer to both `pytorch matmul` and `numpy's matmul`. Casting the params to `tf.float64` also improves the precision. Their GPU implementation of `matmul` (which uses `cublas`) seems to suffer from precision issues.

The closer i got to improve the precision is by native way of implementing `matmul`:

```
tf_output = tf.reduce_sum(tf.expand_dims(tf.transpose(tf_query, (0, 1, 3, 2)), -1)*tf.expand_dims(tf_key,3), 2)
```